# Kafka Consumer.poll under the hood

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As I am newbie about Kafka, wanna know what happens if I call `consumer.poll()` method under the hood. I hypothesized two way of internal behavior as below.

1. The records are fetched as I invoke `poll` method.
2. There is a kind of Queue which records are supplemented by background thread, and `poll` method just taking the records out. (putting aside if queue is empty) If in this case, the max size of queue would be `max.poll.records` configuration.

I delved into the `Consumer` code, and assumed that the second one is right, but can't sure. Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the consumer fetches a record batch, builds an in memory Iterator that you loop over to process records after calling poll function. There's pre-fetch logic as well, to not have a long pause on each poll call.

Not all Kafka client libraries return iterators from poll, rather one record at a time (librdkafka), but the batch fetching is still performed